# d3.js - adding One additional tick for the Y axis does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've drawn a d3 graph using the following.

I want the y axis to have one additional tick. That means, domain range is up to the maximum y value in my data set. And I want one additional tick that is not touched by the graph.

In order to achieve this, I declared a variable where I store the tick count and then in the ticks() of Y Axis I increased it by one.
This does not work, instead the y axis is now blurred.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height - margin.top,
        margin.bottom
    ]).domain([0, max_y]),


    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .innerTickSize(-width + margin.left)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

var ticksCount = yAxis.ticks();
yAxis.ticks(ticksCount + 1);

vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .style({
        'stroke': 'Black',
        'fill': 'none',
        'stroke-width ': 1,
        "font-size": "13px"
    })
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left) + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: I just edited your question. Here is a tip: next time, do not post a *wall of code*. Post only the [MCVE].

Answer (score 2):

`axis.ticks()` as a getter returns an **array**, not a number.

Therefore, this...

```
var ticksCount = yAxis.ticks();
```

... returns the number of ticks (which is `10`) as an array (`[10]`). Then, when you try to add 1 to this array, look what happens:

```js
console.log([10] + 1)
```

You end up with 101 ticks (note: 101 here is actually a string, not a number). That's why you said that *"the y axis is now blurred"*. It's not blurred, you just have a humongous amount of ticks.

You may think that you should do:

```
var ticksCount = yAxis.ticks()[0];
//get the element -------------^ 
yAxis.ticks(ticksCount + 1);
```

But that will make **no** difference: you will have more ticks in the axis, but the minimum/maximum in the axis will be the same.

**Solution**: change the domain instead:

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height - margin.top,
        margin.bottom
    ]).domain([0, max_y * 1.05])
    //add 5% to the top ----^
```

Comment: I changed it like this. domain([0, max_y+max_y * 0.1]). Then it worked. I'm accepting the answer as it gave me the idea. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: You have to explain *why* it doesn't work. It obviously increases the top limit of the domain. Also, have in mind that `max_y+max_y * 0.1` is the same of `max_y*1.1`, have a look: x + 0.1*x = 1*x + 0.1*x = x*(1 + 0.1) = x*1.1.